# predict() error: what can I do if one variable exists in training data but not in prediction data?

Tags: r, regression, glm, lm, predict

I have a training data set with the below variables

```
str(PairsTrain)

'data.frame':   1495698 obs. of  4 variables:  
            $ itemID_1        : int  1 4 8 12 15 19 20 20 22 26 ...  
            $ itemID_2        : int  4112648 1223296 2161930 5637025  113701         
            $ isDuplicate     : int  1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 ...  
            $ generationMethod: int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

I have learned from this dataset using the logistic regression `glm()` function

```
mod1 <- glm(isDuplicate ~., data = PairsTrain, family = binomial)
```

Below is the structure of my test dataset:

```
str(Test)

'data.frame':   1044196 obs. of  3 variables:  
         $ id      : int  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...  
         $ itemID_1: int  5 5 6 11 23 23 30 31 36 47 ...  
         $ itemID_2: int  4670875 787210 1705280 3020777 5316130 3394969 2922567
```

I am trying to make predictions on my test data set like below

```
PredTest <- predict(mod1, newdata = Test, type = "response")
```

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'generationMethod' not found

I get the above error. I am thinking that the reason for the error I am getting is that the number of features in my test dataset doesn't match the training dataset.

I am not sure if I am correct and I am stuck here and don't know how to deal this situation.

Comment: Hi Zheyuan I don't have generationMethod in the test dataset. "id", "itemID_1", "itemID_2" are the only features in the test dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this is all you need:

```
test$generationMethod <- 0
```

You must have variable `generationMethod` in your `test`! It has been used for building models, hence required by `predict` when you make prediction. As you said you don't have this variable in `test`, use the above to create such variable in the `test`. This will have no effect in making prediciton, as this column is all 0; but, it will help you get pass the variable checking by `predict`.

Alternatively, you might consider removing variable `generationMethod` from your model development. Try:

```
mod2 <- glm(isDuplicate ~ itemID_1 + itemID_2, data = PairsTrain,
            family = binomial)
```

Comment: I have tried assigning 0 to genrationMethod and isDuplicate in my test dataset and ran predict function, it did not throw any errors and I have also tried to predict using mod2 model you mentioned, it also worked. Thanks for the help.